# Как узнать какие пакеты можно безболезненно удалить?

Tags: apt-get, debian

Вот остатки от "GNOME 3" (решил попробовать) и, так понимаю, важные библиотеки. Что тут нельзя удалять, и как именно выйти из этого положения?

### A

```
accountsservice
aisleriot
alacarte
apache2.2-bin
apg
argyll
at-spi2-core
```

### B

```
baobab
bluez
bogofilter
bogofilter-bdb
bogofilter-common
brasero
brasero-common
browser-plugin-gnash
```

### C

```
caribou
caribou-antler
cdrdao
cheese-common
cli-common
crda
cups-pk-helper
```

### D

```
dconf-tools
dnsmasq-base
```

### E

```
empathy
empathy-common
espeak-data
evolution-common
evolution-data-server
evolution-data-server-common
evolution-webcal
```

### F

```
finger
folks-common
fonts-cantarell
```

### G

```
gcalctool
gcr
gedit-common
gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
gir1.2-atspi-2.0
gir1.2-caribou-1.0
gir1.2-clutter-1.0
gir1.2-clutter-gst-1.0
gir1.2-cogl-1.0
gir1.2-coglpango-1.0
gir1.2-evince-3.0
gir1.2-folks-0.6
gir1.2-gck-1
gir1.2-gconf-2.0
gir1.2-gcr-3
gir1.2-gdata-0.0
gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0
gir1.2-gee-1.0
gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
gir1.2-goa-1.0
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10
gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10
gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
gir1.2-gtop-2.0
gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
gir1.2-json-1.0
gir1.2-mutter-3.0
gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0
gir1.2-polkit-1.0
gir1.2-soup-2.4
gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2
gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0
gir1.2-tracker-0.14
gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0
gir1.2-webkit-3.0
gir1.2-wnck-3.0
gir1.2-xkl-1.0
gjs
gkbd-capplet
glchess
glines
gnash
gnash-common
gnect
gnibbles
gnobots2
gnome-games
gnome-games-data
gnome-games-extra-data
gnome-icon-theme-extras
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
gnome-nettool
gnome-screenshot
gnome-sudoku
gnome-system-log
gnome-themes-standard-data
gnomine
gnotravex
gnotski
gnuchess
gnuchess-book
grilo-plugins-0.1
gstreamer0.10-nice
gtali
gtk2-engines
gucharmap
guile-2.0-libs
```

### H

```
hwdata
hyphen-en-us
```

### I

```
iagno
iputils-tracepath
iw
```

### L

```
libaccountsservice0
libao-common
libao4
libapache2-mod-dnssd
libapr1
libaprutil1
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
libaprutil1-ldap
libatk-adaptor
libatk-adaptor-data
libatk-bridge2.0-0
libatkmm-1.6-1
libatspi1.0-0
libatspi2.0-0
libaudio2
libavahi-gobject0
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
libblas3gf
libbonobo2-0
libbonobo2-common
libbonoboui2-common
libboost-program-options1.49.0
libboost-thread1.49.0
libbrasero-media3-1
libbrlapi0.5
libcairomm-1.0-1
libcap2-bin
libcaribou-common
libcaribou-gtk-module
libcaribou-gtk3-module
libcaribou0
libchamplain-0.12-0
libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0
libcheese-gtk21
libcheese3
libclutter-1.0-0
libclutter-1.0-common
libclutter-gst-1.0-0
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0
libclutter-imcontext-0.1-bin
libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
libcogl-common
libcogl-pango0
libcogl9
libcolorblind0
libcpufreq0
libdbus-glib1.0-cil
libdbus1.0-cil
libdee-1.0-4
libdiscid0
libdmapsharing-3.0-2
libdotconf1.0
libebackend-1.2-2
libecal-1.2-11
libedata-book-1.2-13
libedata-cal-1.2-15
libedataserverui-3.0-1
libelf1
libepc-1.0-3
libepc-common
libepc-ui-1.0-3
libespeak1
libexempi3
libfarstream-0.1-0
libfolks-eds25
libfolks-telepathy25
libfolks25
libgail-common
libgck-1-0
libgconf2.0-cil
libgcr-3-1
libgcr-3-common
libgdata-common
libgdata13
libgdict-1.0-6
libgdict-common
libgdiplus
libgdu-gtk0
libgee2
libgeocode-glib0
libgexiv2-1
libgjs0b
libglib2.0-bin
libglib2.0-cil
libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
libgmime-2.6-0
libgmime2.6-cil
libgnome-bluetooth10
libgnome-mag2
libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
libgnome-menu-3-0
libgnome2-common
libgnomecanvas2-0
libgnomecanvas2-common
libgnomekbd-common
libgnomekbd7
libgnomeui-common
libgoa-1.0-0
libgoa-1.0-common
libgpod-common
libgpod4
libgrilo-0.1-0
libgsf-1-114
libgsf-1-common
libgsl0ldbl
libgssdp-1.0-3
libgtk-vnc-2.0-0
libgtk2.0-cil
libgtkhtml-4.0-0
libgtkhtml-4.0-common
libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0
libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a
libgtkmm-3.0-1
libgtksourceview-3.0-0
libgtksourceview-3.0-common
libgtkspell0
libgucharmap-2-90-7
libgupnp-1.0-4
libgupnp-av-1.0-2
libgupnp-dlna-1.0-2
libgupnp-igd-1.0-4
libgvnc-1.0-0
libgweather-3-0
libgweather-common
libicc2
libidl0
libimdi0
libiptcdata0
libjim0debian2
libjson-glib-1.0-0
liblinear-tools
liblinear1
liblircclient0
liblouis-data
liblouis2
libmeanwhile1
libminiupnpc5
libmission-control-plugins0
libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
libmono-addins0.2-cil
libmono-cairo4.0-cil
libmono-corlib4.0-cil
libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
libmono-i18n4.0-cil
libmono-posix4.0-cil
libmono-security4.0-cil
libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil
libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
libmono-system-core4.0-cil
libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil
libmono-system-security4.0-cil
libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
libmono-system4.0-cil
libmozjs185-1.0
libmtp-common
libmtp-runtime
libmtp9
libmusicbrainz5-0
libmutter0
libmx-1.0-2
libmx-bin
libmx-common
libnatpmp1
libnetfilter-conntrack3
libnice10
libnl-3-200
libnl-genl-3-200
libnl-route-3-200
libnm-glib-vpn1
libnm-gtk-common
libnm-gtk0
liboauth0
liborbit2
libpackagekit-glib2-14
libpam-cap
libpam-gnome-keyring
libpanel-applet-4-0
libpangomm-1.4-1
libpeas-common
libpst4
libpulse-mainloop-glib0
libpurple-bin
libpurple0
libquvi-scripts
libquvi7
libraw5
libreadline5
librest-0.7-0
librest-extras-0.7-0
libsocialweb-client2
libsocialweb-common
libsocialweb-service
libsocialweb0
libsofia-sip-ua-glib3
libsofia-sip-ua0
libsonic0
libspeechd2
libsvm-tools
libtelepathy-farstream2
libtelepathy-logger2
libtidy-0.99-0
libtotem-plparser17
libtracker-extract-0.14-0
libtracker-miner-0.14-0
libtracker-sparql-0.14-0
libunique-3.0-0
libunistring0
libwacom-common
libwacom2
libwnck-3-0
libwnck-3-common
libxss1
libyelp0
libzephyr4
lightsoff
```

### M

```
mahjongg
media-player-info
minissdpd
mobile-broadband-provider-info
modemmanager
mono-4.0-gac
mono-gac
mono-runtime
mousetweaks
mutter-common
```

### N

```
nautilus-sendto-empathy
network-manager
network-manager-gnome
nmap
```

### O

```
obexd-client
```

### P

```
packagekit
packagekit-backend-aptcc
packagekit-tools
perlmagick
pidgin-data
python-beautifulsoup
python-brlapi
python-feedparser
python-gconf
python-httplib2
python-libxml2
python-louis
python-mako
python-markupsafe
python-packagekit
python-pyatspi
python-pyatspi2
python-pyorbit
python-speechd
python-utidylib
python-wnck
python-zeitgeist
```

### Q

```
quadrapassel
```

### R

```
rdesktop
rhythmbox-data
rygel
rygel-playbin
rygel-preferences
rygel-tracker
```

### S

```
shotwell
shotwell-common
simple-scan
sound-juicer
sound-theme-freedesktop
speech-dispatcher
swell-foop
```

### T

```
telepathy-gabble
telepathy-haze
telepathy-idle
telepathy-logger
telepathy-mission-control-5
telepathy-rakia
telepathy-salut
tomboy
totem-common
tracker
tracker-extract
tracker-gui
tracker-miner-fs
tracker-utils
transmission-common
transmission-gtk
```

### U

```
unoconv
usb-modeswitch
usb-modeswitch-data
```

### V

```
vinagre
vino
```

### W

```
wireless-regdb
wpasupplicant
```

### X

```
xbrlapi
xdg-user-dirs-gtk
```

### Y

```
yelp
yelp-xsl
```

### Z

```
zeitgeist-core
```

Comment: отличный вопрос

Comment: А где вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять какие пакеты не используются рекомендую установить с репозиториев дебиана программу deborphan.После введя комманду "deborphan --guess-all", Вы узнаете какие пакеты можно удалить, т.к. их не использует система.